# Django Save Form Admin

Tags: django

how to insert or save each block separated by # in an inline in the Django admin.

Pleas check this image: http://uppix.net/4/a/5/9cf44beb3f4b166c48b25009198f9.png

**['my_link_1 my_link_2', 'my_link_any', 'my_link_any3']**

Each block separated by # it's a one new inline whit the same

Result:
http://uppix.net/e/4/c/f04ad6ac5dc21542ca89bde5da31c.png

Do I'm can use save_formset()

Thanks.

Comment: It's too difficult to understand what you are trying to do? Insert a # after every newline in a `TextArea`?

Comment: @djangopy your urls don't work.

Comment: @Timmy O'Mahony Yes I'm tried add each block split when # in new inline when save object.